# A phenomenon where a file type comes out differently on a specific computer

Tags: file, video, upload, quicktime

Uploading a video file to a stock site.
I checked that the file type is displayed as 'video/mov' only on that computer when I upload the file.
On other computers, it is marked as 'video/quicktime' and the file upload works fine without any problems.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5LpB.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTUuO.png)
Is it a problem with browser settings, or is it a problem with computer codecs?

I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Different codecs can give different formats of files, The file type (or format) is basically the encoded data and contains information about how the data is formatted, and what kind of compression is used. As a result, codecs can be one of the reasons for this issue.

[what is codecs](https://www.techtarget.com/searchunifiedcommunications/definition/codec)

Comment: It's the same file, but the results are different depending on the computer.

Comment: Codecs can be hardware or software